# VSTO: How can I Drag the "Excel RibbonBox" position？

Tags: excel, position, vsto, ribbon, box

[image]

I can't drag Box5 under Box1 . And don't know why When I add a new box, it always default insert into top.
I already tried to google this situation, not working. And the visual studio RibbonBox attribute seem don't have this set item.
How can I  Drag the "Excel RibbonBox" position？